# Concatenate string with escape characters to bookend string with "\"... \"" in R

Tags: r, concatenation, escaping

I have a character vector of file paths that look like this:

```
xx <- c("data/lsa_two_isl_prosp_u.csv",
        "data/lsa_two_isl_prosp_d.csv" , 
        "data/lsa_two_isl_propsuit_u.csv")
```

However, I need these file paths to have "" concatenated on to the beginning of the string and "" concatenated onto the end, so that my string looks like this:

```
xx <- c("\"data/lsa_two_isl_prosp_u.csv\"",
        "\"data/lsa_two_isl_prosp_d.csv\"" , 
        "\"data/lsa_two_isl_propsuit_u.csv\"")
```

Normally I would use paste but the `"\"... \""`  are escape characters that need each other to 'bookend' a string.

In hindsight, an obviously doomed idea, but sharing to avoid anyone else who might try: If I try yo use `paste('"\"', xx, '\""')` , I get `"\"\" data/lsa_two_isl_prosp_d.csv \"\""` , which is obviously wrong, and I cannot remove the excess portions of the string without throwing out all of it, incase you may have the same idea...

Any suggestions?

Comment: `paste0('"', xx, '"')`? `dQuote(xx)`? (`dQuote(xx, FALSE)` on windows)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after a lot of trial and error:

```
xx <- paste("\"", xx, "\"")
```